# Add a Panel in a templated control UWP

Tags: uwp, panel

I have a  "class MyTemplatedControl : Control" and then I have no XAML. How can I inser a Panel in MyTemplatedControl in runtime?

Comment: Panel.Childxx.Add(xx)

Comment: Inside MyTemplatedControl I have no Panel. I could use Panel.Childxx.Add(xx) (if Panel stands for an instance of class Panel) if I had a Panel in MyTemplatedControl and I would insert a control xx inside the Panel itself.
If Panel stands for the class itself then the classPanel has a static property ChildrenTransitionsProperty which has no Add method. If I'm not wrong

Comment: Did you create a templated control? I mean in your visual studio, when you add new ,did you choose a `Class` or `Templated Control`?

Comment: Templated Control. I have a "public sealed class MyTemplatedControl : Control"